# Kubernetes - Get EBS Volume of a Pod

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

Using `kubectl`, how would I go about identifying what volume a specific pod resides on?

I tried `kubectl describe pod [podname]` and I can get the Node that its on but I'm not able to find anything regarding the EBS volume.

Comment: Can you first identify the associated PersistentVolume bound to the pod/PVC, and then describe that PV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `kubectl describe pod [podname]` you will get the node where your pod is sitting. In output the node you will get in attribute `Node: ip-192-168-0-219.us-east-2.compute.internal/192.168.0.219`. But you have to copy only `ip-192-168-0-219.us-east-2.compute.internal` this part. After that just describe that node using `kubectl describe node [node_id]`. You will get the EBS volume of pod.